# Sequential compactness implies compactness: what is wrong with this argument?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, filters, nets

**Definitions**

1. A *filter* is a poset $(I,\leq)$ such that for any $\alpha,\beta\in I$ there is $\gamma\in I$ such that $\gamma\geq\beta,\gamma\geq\alpha$.
2. A *net* in a set $X$ is a function from a poset to $X$.
3. A *subnet* of a net $(f(\alpha))_{\alpha\in I}$ is a net
   $(f(g(\beta)))_{\beta\in J}$ where $g:J\to I$ tends to infinity,
   i.e. for any $\alpha\in I$ we have $\beta_\alpha$ such that
   $\beta\geq\beta_\alpha\implies g(\beta)\geq\alpha$.
4. A net $(f(\alpha))_{\alpha\in I}\subseteq X$ where $X$ is a
   topological space *converges to $x\in X$* if for every neighborhood
   $U$ of $x$ there is $\alpha_U\in I$ such that
   $\alpha\geq\alpha_U\implies f(\alpha)\in U$.

I will indicate a net $(f(\alpha))_{\alpha\in I}$ by $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha\in I}$ where $x_\alpha=f(\alpha)$.

**Lemma**

For any infinite filter $I$ there exists $f:\mathbb{N}\to I$ which tends to infinity in the sense of definition 3.

*Proof*.

Set $\alpha_1=f(1)$ for any $\alpha_1\in I$. We can always find $\beta\neq\alpha_1$ unless the filter is a single point, which is impossible since we assumed it is infinite. So we have either $\beta\geq\alpha_1$ or $\alpha_1\geq\beta$. If the former, set $f(2)=\beta$. If the latter, set $f(1)=\beta,f(2)=\alpha_1$. Better rename. Filter is infinite, so we find a third element distinct from all 3. Order them and set $f(1)$ to be the minimum, $f(2)$ the middle point, $f(3)$ the maximum. If the three elements form a branch (i.e. we have $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ with $\alpha\leq\beta,\alpha\leq\gamma$ but $\beta,\gamma$ not comparable), then $f(1)=\alpha,f(2)=\beta$, and by definition of filter you find $\gamma':\gamma'\geq\beta,\gamma'\geq\gamma$, and so $\alpha,\beta,\gamma'$ form a totally ordered subset and $f(3)=\gamma'$ makes $f$ increasing from $\{1,2,3\}$ to the filter considered. By such arguments, one can inductively construct $f(n)$ for any $n$, proving the claim.

**Lemma**

Let $I$ be a finite filter. Then any net from $I$ to any topological space converges.

*Proof*.

Pick any $a\in I$. If there is $b\geq a$, replace $a$ with $b$. In a finite number of steps, you will have reached a maximal $a$. $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha\in I}$ will converge to $x_a$, since the definition states that for any $U$ neighborhood of $x_a$ we must find $b\in I:c\geq b\implies x_c\in U$, but $b=a$ implies $c\geq b$ equates to $c=b=a$ so we conclude.

In fact, the above shows we wouldn't want to consider finite filters for nets, since if a finite filter has a branch then it has at least two distinct maximal elements $a\neq b$ and so any net for which $x_a\neq x_b$ will converge to two distinct points, impeding uniqueness of limits.

It is known ([see here](http://www.mat.unimi.it/users/libor/AnConvessa/nets.pdf)) that $X$ is compact iff every net has a convergent subnet.

**Lemma**

Any net from an infinite filter has a subnet which is a sequence.

*Proof*.

We have proven above that there exists $f$ from the naturals to the filter which tends to infinity. We have $(x_\alpha)$ a net. Just set $y_n=x_{f(n)}$ and you have your subnet sequence.

**Theorem**

Sequential compactness implies compactness.

*Proof*.

Take a net $(x_\alpha)$. By the lemma above we can find a subnet which is a sequence, so $(x_{f(n)})$. By hypothesis this sequence has a convergent subsequence $(x_{f(g(n))})$. But this is a convergent subnet to $x_\alpha$, hence compactness.

Great! Except there are counterexamples, i.e. spaces which are sequentially compact but not compact. So what did I get wrong here?

**Update**

Naturally the thing about finite filters is that no branching can avoid reconnecting. But that is general: if I have two maximal elements, they are either equal or they cannot both be maximal, since for any two distinct elements there is a third above both. Hence the remark on "I wouldn't want to consider finite filters for nets" is just bogus :).

Comment: The first lemma is wrong. If $I = \omega_1$, where $\omega_1$ is the first uncountable ordinal, then all maps $f\colon \mathbb{N}\to I$ are bounded. (I haven't looked further, and have no time now, will look after dinner.)

Comment: People have pointed out that Lemma 1 is false. You asked what's wrong with the proof. In the non-proof of Lemma 1 you construct $f$ just fine. Then you give no indication whatever why it should tend to infinity (in general it doesn't).

Comment: Without reading, the easiest way to know that a fake proof to a known false statement is to pick a concrete counterexample and apply the proof to it in details (as necessary). So take a compact space which is not sequentially compact (e.g. one point compactification of an uncountable discrete space) and see where your proof fails when trying to apply it there.

Comment: Well the counterexample here would rather be a sequentially compact but not compact space, like $\omega_1$, which I previously knew next to nothing of, so I couldn't really apply the proof there. Good suggestion anyway, in genera, @Asaf.

Comment: Right, the other way around. As I said, without reading. I'm all about abstractions and generalizations, even when it comes to advice. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lemma 1 is wrong, it states that every "filter" (better use "directed set", which is more standard) has a convergent subsequence, essentially. But there are linearly or partially ordered sets that do not have countable cofinality:

Take e.g. $I = \omega_1$, the first uncountable ordinal, then any function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow I$ is bounded above, i.e. there is some $\beta \in \omega_1$ such that $f(n) \le \beta$ for all $n$. And then it cannot converge in your sense 3, because $f$ never gets above $\beta+1 \in \omega_1$.

The rest falls down after that (the lemma on finite index sets is true, but irrelevant).

What *is* true is that sequential compactness implies countable compactness, but no more: $\omega_1$ in the order topology is sequentially compact but not compact.

And spaces like $\beta\mathbb{N}$ and $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{R}$ are compact but not sequentially compact.

Comment: [To know what $\omega_1$ is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrU9YDoXE88). Sorry, my knowledge of ordinals is at this level :). How is the boundedness of any $f$ shown? What is the order topology on $\omega_1$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_uncountable_ordinal It has links to all those statements.

Comment: Is it correct to say that the topology induced from $[0,\omega_1)$ on any $[x\omega,(x+1)\omega)$ (therein including $[\omega_1-\omega,\omega_1)$) is discrete, and that taking a cover of $[0,\omega_1-\omega]$ plus the singletons of $[\omega_1-\omega,\omega_1)$ gives me a cover of $[0,\omega_1)$ with no finite subcover?

Comment: @MickG No, not quite. But simpler: $[0,\alpha), \alpha < \omega_1$ are all open sets (increasing) that cover $\omega_1$ but it does not have any countable (or finite) subcover, because then the countably many upper limits have an even larger upperbound that is not covered by them.

Comment: Is "not quite" referrig to the induced topologies, the proposed cover with no finite subcover, or both? And what is wrong with what I said?

Comment: Yes, the intervals $[\alpha\omega, (\alpha+1)\omega)$ are discrete, but there are many more countable ordinals than that (and limits too). So they don't cover all. And $\omega_1 - \omega$ is not an ordinal smaller (as $\omega_1$ is a limit), but sort of undefined. There are a lot of isolated points, but a lot of countable limit ordinals too.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/44921/4280 is a related answer.

Comment: $\omega_1-\omega$ is undefined for a similar reason as why $\omega-1$ is undefined, right? I found [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/172611) via googling. I'm trying to figure out why what he says about the $\beta$ at the end holds.

Comment: Indeed. The answer by Brian is excellent. Munkres also covers $\omega_1$ but he calls it $\Omega$.

Comment: Oh. You had linked it already, but the comment wasn't yet showing in the app :).

Comment: About cofinality: [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofinality), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofinal_%28mathematics%29).

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite an answer, but rather a sum-up of what I gathered on ordinals from various sources. First of all we have [the comments to Henno's answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mh5ri.png) (links in the screenshot: [Vsauce video in first comment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrU9YDoXE88), [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_uncountable_ordinal), [Related answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/44921/4280), [post found by me via googling](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/172611)). Then we have [this other Math SX post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1537530/135592) and [this third one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/135331/135592). Finally, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) and [more Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology).

- Basically, an ordinal is an order type, so an equivalence class of well-orders under "order isomorphism", where an order isomorphism between well-ordered sets $I,J$ is, I take it, a bijective order-preserving function with order-preserving inverse; this can be alternately viewed with the Von Neumann approach, where an ordinal is a well-ordered set such that every element of it is also a subset;
- Ordinals can be topologized with the order topology, generated by the subbase of open rays $[0,\alpha)$ for $\alpha$ an ordinal; with this, sets of the form $[\alpha\omega,(\alpha+1)\omega)$ are discrete, whereas if we add in $(\alpha+1)\omega$ (i.e. consider the closed interval $[\alpha\omega,(\alpha+1)\omega]$), it is not discrete since $(\alpha+1)\omega$ is a limit point; those sets are certainly open, but not an open cover, as the comments say;
- $I=[0,\omega_1)$, with $\omega_1$ the first uncountable ordinal (which exists by well-ordering, since the set of uncountable ordinals must have a least element $\omega_1$), is not compact, since $[0,\alpha)$ for $\alpha\in I$ is an open cover but no finite subcover exists, since if there were one the union of all the upper limits would be $\beta$, an ordinal such that $[0,\beta)$ contains all the subcover, but a countable one; that a union of ordinals is an ordinal comes from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/135331/135592);
- Just like $\omega-1$, $\omega_1-\omega$ is sort of undefined;
- [$I$ has no countable closed discrete subset](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/172611); the link's argument is: let $A$ ba such a set; let $A_c=\{\alpha\in I:\alpha\geq\beta\text{ for countably many }\beta\in A\}$; $A_c$ is nonempty (because the union of all $\alpha+1$ for $\alpha\in A$ is an ordinal strictly greater than all of $A$) so by well-ordering ([here is the proof of the well-order property of $I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1537530/135592)) it has a least element $\beta$; $\beta$ is a limit point of $A$ (why? Will think in a while…), so either $\beta\in A$ and $A$ is not discrete, or $\beta\not\in A$ so $A$ is not closed;
- The union argument above clearly shows that any $f:\mathbb{N}\to\omega_1$ is bounded above, because the image of $f$ is at most countable, and so is bounded by $\bigcup_n(f(n)+1)$; so no such $f$ can tend to infinity;
- $\omega_1$ is first countable since the rays that generate its topology are countable (right?); so a sequence in $\omega_1$, having a limit point as seen above (and why $\beta$ is a limit point still escapes me), must have a convergent subsequence to that limit point, since for any $U_n$ of the countable local base at $\beta$ I find $a_n\in U_n$ from the sequence, and since there are countably many "$a_n$"s I can find $k(n)$ an increasing function such that $a_{k(n)}\in U_n$ for all $n$.

Anything wrong here?

Comment: The order topology also has all right segment $(\alpha, \rightarrow)$ in its subbase, not just the initial segments. $\omega_1 - \omega$ is defined, it's just $\omega_1$, because $\omega + \omega_1 = \omega_1$ (as ordinals), so it's not some ordinal less than $\omega_1$, as people often think. See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Ordinal_Subtraction_when_Possible_is_Unique